# Jquery Modal Dialog With Login and Registration

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a Jquery modal window for login and registration. The modal window is dynamically injected into the body of the page via ajax when a css trigger on the page is clicked. The default form displayed when the modal window opens is the login form. At this point everything works (form validation, ajax submit etc.) as expected. The script always works fine with whichever form is set as default.

If the user does not have an account yet, he/she can click on a link to display the registration form. At this point the login form fades out and the registration form fades in.

However, when I switch to the registration form, jquery doesn't redefine the plActiveForm variable as instructed by the script in plMShowRegBtn and plMShowLoginBtn click events. If I make the registration form the default form, then everything works fine until I switch to the login form at which point I experience the same problem - jquery just does not execute on the form -- but all other jquery works fine (such as closing the modal window and removing it from the markup).

It seems that once the jquery is loaded and the value is defined for the plActiveForm variable, it won't let me redefine it. This variable holds the ID of the current form and is used throughout the code.

I have tried using the plMShowRegBtn and plMShowLoginBtn click event with live() and on() function to no avail.

The html portion is not shown here but it is very simple. A div container with two forms -- one for login and one for registration and two input buttons to switch the forms displayed. Both forms are css display:none by default.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

My plugin is shown below:

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// JQUERY - FOR MODAL LOGIN + REGISTRATION FORM
// -----------------------------------------------
(function ($) {
$.fn.plMlogin = function (options) {

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // DEFAULTS AND OPTIONS
    // -----------------------------------------------
    var defaults = {
        plTooltip: true,
        plResetButton: true,
        plBubbleResponse: true
    };
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // SHOW MODAL WINDOW ON CLICK
    // -----------------------------------------------
    $('.pl-m-trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // -> append container into body
        $('body').append('<div class="pl-m-container">');

        // -> load modal forms into container
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pl-module/public/modal-login-html.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds
            success: function(html) {

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // -> LOAD FORMS INTO CONTAINER
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(".pl-m-container").html(html);

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // PROPERTIES
                // -----------------------------------------------
                var plMContainer = $('.pl-m-container'),
                    plMWrap = $('.pl-m'),
                    plMOverlay = $('.pl-m-overlay'),
                    plMLoginFrm = $('#pl_frmMlogin'),
                    plMRegFrm = $('#pl_frmMRegister'),
                    plMLoading = $('.pl-loading'),
                    plMCloseBtn = $('.pl-m-close'),
                    plMShowRegBtn = $('#pl_showRegForm'),
                    plMShowLoginBtn = $('#pl_showLoginForm'),
                    plMLoginSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/login.php',
                    plMRegisterSubmitUrl = 'pl-module/public/register.php',
                    plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm,
                    plSubmitUrl = plMLoginSubmitUrl;

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SHOW MODAL WINDOW AND DEFAULT FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMWrap).fadeIn('fast');
                $(plMOverlay).fadeIn('fast');
                $(plActiveForm).fadeIn('fast');

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // CLOSE MODAL WINDOW ON BTN CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMCloseBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(plMWrap).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(plMOverlay).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                            $(plMContainer).remove();
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // CLOSE MODAL WINDOW ON OVERLAY CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMOverlay).click(function() {
                    $(plMWrap).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                            $(plMContainer).remove();
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SWITCH TO REGISTRATION FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMShowRegBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plResetForm();
                    $(plMLoginFrm).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(plMRegFrm).slideDown('fast', function(){
                            // set active form to registration
                            plActiveForm = plMRegFrm;
                            plSubmitUrl = plMRegisterSubmitUrl;
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // SWITCH TO LOGIN FORM
                // -----------------------------------------------
                $(plMShowLoginBtn).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    plResetForm();
                    $(plMRegFrm).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(plMLoginFrm).slideDown('fast', function(){
                            // set active form to login
                            plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm;
                            plSubmitUrl = plMLoginSubmitUrl;
                        });
                    });
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESPONSE MESSAGES
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plResponse(plMsg, plShowHide) {
                    var plResponse = $('.pl-response', plActiveForm);
                    if (plShowHide === true) {
                        $(plResponse).fadeIn('slow').html(plMsg);
                    } else if (plShowHide === false) {
                        $(plResponse).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESET FORM BUTTON CLICK
                // -----------------------------------------------
                if (settings.plResetButton) {
                    var plResetBtn = $('.pl-reset-btn', plActiveForm);

                    $(plResetBtn).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        plResetForm();
                    });
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // RESET FORM FUNCTION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plResetForm() {
                    $('.pl-cust-response', plActiveForm).remove();
                    $('.pl-error', plActiveForm).removeClass('pl-error');
                    plResponse('', false);
                    plResetBtn.hide();
                    $(plActiveForm)[0].reset();
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // FORM VALIDATION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plValidate() {
                    // remove custom errors if visible
                    $('.pl-cust-response', plActiveForm).remove();

                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // CHECK - EMPTY REQUIRED FIELDS
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    $(plActiveForm).find('.pl-required').each(function () {
                        var plEmptyCheck = $.trim($(this).val());
                        if (plEmptyCheck.length == 0) {
                            plResponse(PLLANG.MSG_03, true);
                            if (settings.plBubbleResponse) {
                                $(this).parent().append('<span class="pl-cust-response">' + PLLANG.MSG_04 + '</span>');
                                $('.pl-cust-response').fadeIn('slow');
                            }
                            $(this).addClass('pl-error');
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass('pl-error');
                        }
                    });

                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    // IF ERROR(S) FOUND
                    // -----------------------------------------------
                    var $errors = $('.pl-error', plActiveForm);
                    if ($errors.length > 0) {
                        if (settings.plResetButton) {
                            plResetBtn.show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        plResponse('', false);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // FORM SUBMIT
                // -----------------------------------------------
                plActiveForm.submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // if validation is ok
                    if (plValidate() === true) {
                        var plFormData = $(this).serialize();
                        plAjaxSubmit(plFormData);
                        $(plMLoading).show();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                // -----------------------------------------------
                // AJAX SUBMIT FUNCTION
                // -----------------------------------------------
                function plAjaxSubmit(plFormData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: plSubmitUrl,
                        data: plFormData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        timeout: 20000,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                if (value.error == true) {
                                    // hide loading image
                                    $(plMLoading).hide();

                                    plResponse(value.msg, true);

                                    // show reset button
                                    if (settings.plResetButton) {
                                        plResetBtn.show();
                                    }
                                } else if (value.error == false) {
                                    // reset form
                                    plResetForm();

                                    // hide loading image
                                    $(plMLoading).hide();

                                    // display success message
                                    plResponse(value.msg, true);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            plResponse(PLLANG.MSG_06, true);

                            // hide loading image
                            $(plMLoading).hide();
                        },
                        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, status) {
                            // hide loading image
                            $(plMLoading).hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);

// -----------------------------------------------
// INSTANTIATE MODAL LOGIN
// -----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pl-m').plMlogin({
        plTooltip : true,
        plResetButton : true,
        plBubbleResponse : true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a separate plugin that handles the modal window and loading the file sent to it - very compact and the only reference that needs to be included into the page. Forms have their own plugin that handle all the validation and other functionality. The forms and their related js are injected into the page by the modal plugin trigger action which makes the whole operation virtually weightless. Everything is dynamically added and then removed....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scope issue. Try moving your "properties" decarlations out of the ajax success and into the main body of the plugin. As an example:

```
$.fn.plMlogin = function (options) {
    // declare private properties here
    var plActiveForm, plMLoginFrm; // etc.
```

and in the ajax success function, set the properties without making them local with `var`:

```
plMLoginFrm = $('#pl_frmMlogin');
plActiveForm = plMLoginFrm;
```

Comment: I have tried shuffling the code around in a lot of different ways to no avail. It seems to me that I have to be inside at least the trigger click event but I am probably wrong.